# StandardTile and GenericTile in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Can I put a `StandardTile` and a `GenericTile` into the same `TileContainer`?

I'm trying unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please show us what you tried, we can then perhaps help.

Comment: `StandardTile` and `TileContainer` are now **deprecated** (since version 1.50). According to the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.TileContainer), a container of your choice with `GenericTile` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that you have to put it into a customTile like that:

```
<CustomTile class="myCustomTile">  
  <content>  
  <suite:GenericTile   
     size="M"   
     frameType="TwoByOne"  
     press="press"  
     backgroundImage="data/NewsImage1.png">  
     <suite:tileContent>  
       <suite:TileContent footer="August 21, 2013" size="M">  
         <suite:content>  
           <suite:NewsContent   
             size="M"   
             contentText="SAP Unveils Powerful New Player Comparison Tool Exclusively on NFL.com"   
             subheader="SAP News">  
           </suite:NewsContent>  
         </suite:content>  
       </suite:TileContent>  
     </suite:tileContent>  
   </suite:GenericTile>  
  </content>  
  </CustomTile>
```

check this post on [scn](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3675645)